# Can't understand what this code do

Tags: c

Can anyone help me with explanation what this line do

```
(UserList *) malloc(sizeof(UserList));
```

I'm new to C world. What I understand is that allocate memory for Userlist type. 
If so why definition is not just

```
Userlist malloc(sizeof(UserList))  ?
```

Comment: We need more context. I guess the first line could be a cast. But you would probably assign it to something.

Comment: Arguing syntax (ie, questions like "why isn't it like this instead...?") seems kind of.. pointless, don't you think? It is what it is.

Comment: Answer: this code as it is does exactly nothing of any use.

Comment: @PeteWilson, right, of course, any code does precisely nothing getting it out of context... I don't think your answer is of any use either in this context...

Comment: @Pete Wilson: Who knows, maybe someone wants to hog RAM?

Comment: @undur_gonor -- well, maybe so. and I gave you an upvote for your comment :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What this code is doing is allocating dynamic memory for a structure of type `UserList`. The previous expression, `(UserList*)` tells the compiler of what type to treat that value returned by `malloc`. As `malloc` is generic in C and can return a pointer to any type (effectively in C terminology, `void*`), you can tell the compiler what type do you expect this pointer points to. This usually happens in the context of an initialization of a variable of type `UserList*`:

```
UserList* user_list = (UserList *) malloc(sizeof(UserList));
```

Note how the variable getting the result is a pointer to the correct type. You can access to the structure pointed by the pointer in this new allocated memory using the normal `*user_list` syntax.

Comment: Actually, not only do you NOT have to tell the compiler what type the memory is, it's actually frowned upon by the C community.

Comment: @Blindy: Yes, thanks, corrected it just when I re-read it. :)

Answer (score 0):

malloc returns a pointer (memory location) to the memory allocated. The * means a "pointer to" a UserList rather than the userlist itself.

I'm not sure if this line is a declaration or a statement. If it's a statement then the brackets cause the type of the pointer returned to be cast to "pointer to UserList" rather than "void *" meaning pointer to anything.